# DIV class is not being displayed in grid view

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am not exactly sure as to why this is happening but

> The `DIV` class elements are being outputted to the browser in a single
>   vertical view rather then horizontal view.

**As such: i.imgur.com/olChE92.png**

I do know that the CSS is correct and the horizontal view is displayed however I am making a new site and for this I choose to have position "fixed" left sidebar with background scrolling to the very bottom and a position "fixed" upper menu only leaving the actual file manager field to scroll the content.

**As such: i.imgur.com/DKqZp2s.jpg**

Also the content is injected into a DIV ID via jQuery AJAX JSON and from JSON data jQuery builds the file data into the DIV classes and outputs them all into page ones its done.

Also here is the JSFiddle with full HTML + CSS + JQUERY: jsfiddle.net/HgsVh/2/

In any event here is the code for **File.css** which is responsible for the actual way files our outputted into pre-defined DIV ID

```
.product {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px #dedede solid;
    padding: 5px;
    background-image: url(images/corner.jpg);
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.product:hover {
    background-color: #87c6f1;
    /* #fae7af */
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px #cdcdcd solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #87c6f1, 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.product .title {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #cdcdcd;
}

.product img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.setting {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/preferences.png);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.like {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_46.png);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.like:hover {
    background-image: url(http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_44.png);
}

.product .description {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Now here is the **Style.css** for the main page where there being outputted

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
}

#content>#menu {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#filemanager {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}

#sidemenu {
    background: #191818;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    border-right: 10px solid #eee;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    top: 0px;
    width: 190px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
}
```

And here is the last part of the code the jQuery snippet in the index.php which is responsible for injecting the data it gets from JSON callback into #filemanager-ajax DIV located inside #filemanager DIV

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON('file.php?path=<?php echo $_GET['path']; ?>&callback=?', function (data) {
    $("#filemanager-ajax").html('');
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

        $("#filemanager-ajax").fadeIn(4000);

        $("#filemanager-ajax").append('<a class="link" href="' + item.id + '"><div class="product" data="' + item.path + '"><img src="' + item.thumb + '" title="' + item.thumb + '" class="thumbnail"/><div class="title">' + item.name + '</div><div class="description"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Filesize:</strong> ' + item.size + '<div style="clear:both;height:8px;"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;about ' + item.date + ' ago<div style="clear:both;height:8px;"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></a>');

     });
 });
     });
```

This is really all, ones more the File.css works fine if its being output into a single full page element but when there are few elements to the side it does not work. Here is the Wireframe drawing explaining the DIV's and what I meant if you where not exactly sure and as well as an image of how the elements for .product class are being outputted

**Wireframe Diagram:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP1gz.jpg
**.product output:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgAke.png

Kindly thanks in advance and sorry for so much code.

Comment: you're probably going to need to put the HTML before we know whats going on

Comment: @Chad a sorry not a problem I added a JSFiddle to the original post, but for your convenience here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/HgsVh/2/